# Customizing Index in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to customize index page like display details based on id. For example i have two tables like merchant and customer

merchant.rb

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :customers
end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :merchant
end
```

Present my code is like

```
app/admin/merchant.rb

index  do
  selectable_column
  column :merchant_id
  column :name
  actions   
end
```

It displays the Merchant Id and Merchant name, on click merchant_id it should show the related customers. Give some ideas to implement

Comment: based on concrete `merchant_id`? And specify the problem. Is it just fetching the customers?

Comment: yes!!! based on merchant_id

Comment: `column :merchant_name`

 `column :number do |a|`

  `a.customer.number `
 `end`
 `column :name do |a|`
  `a.customer.name` 
 `end`                                  
Present i am fetching customer like these.. i want show details like **Merchant id: 1**
customer_name     number
**Merchant id:2**
customer_name    number

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it throwing me error like **undefined local variable or method `merchant_id' for #<Admin::CustomersController:0x00000007df2558>**

Comment: Try to reformulate your original question with examples, so that someone who tries to answer at least gets what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be practical to show all customers for each merchant in a single row, so usually I would prefer to show a customer count and link it to the customer index with merchant filter set.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Merchant do
  def scoped_collection
    super.select('merchants.*, COUNT(*) AS customer_count')
         .joins(:customers)
         .group('merchants.id')
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column

    column :customer_count, sortable: 'customer_count' do |merchant|
      link_to merchant.attributes['customer_count'],
              admin_customers_path(q: { merchant_id_eq: merchant.id })
    end

    actions
  end
end
```